# How do I disable text wrapping in a multiline text control in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating my text control like this:

```
wx.TextCtrl(
    panel, style=wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_DONTWRAP | wx.HSCROLL
)
```

I've tried with all combinations of `wx.TE_DONTWRAP` and `wx.HSCROLL` but my text input still wraps all text. I want the text control to **never** wrap any lines and instead add a horizontal scrollbar. [Here is the full code](http://pastebin.com/Le9P3KeU), the interesting lines are *171:187*.

---

I'm using **wxPython 2.9.4.0** on **OSX 10.8.1** (Mountain Lion).

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and text_input_panel works as expected for me. I use wx2.8.12.1, python 2.7, windows vista.

Comment: So it **should** work... I added my version and OS info in the question.

Comment: @ErwinP: Forgot to refer to you. Also added a screenshot now.

Comment: There seem to be some related bugs here: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/11321 http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4022

Comment: @pythonm: In both those bug reports there at least was no text wrapping. I can't even get past that.

Comment: Why do you have it set to multiline if you don't want it to wrap? While this works on Windows, it is unintuitive as I would expect it to wrap by looking at it visually. You should cross-post to the wxPython mailing list. There are several Mac guys there who can probably weigh in.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I don't understand the question. I have it set to multiline so that I can have line breaks in the text box. What does that have to do with text wrapping?

Comment: When I see a multi-line text control, I just expect it to wrap. Anyway, I still recommend asking on the wxPython mailing list. Several of the wxPython devs are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this just doesn't work on OSX with Python 2.9. I switched to using a [StyledTextCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html) instead which works excellently.

Comment: Hi, could you post your new code so I can see how it worked for you in the end please? Cheers.